# Micro integrator using connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm trying to run the WSO2 Micro integrator on docker. When not using any form of connector this seems to work. However I now have need for the amazon sqs connector.

When using the Intergration studio 7.0.0, I have successfully imported the connector from the store and used the  in one of my sequences. It shows up in the Design-mode of the studio. 
I used the SQS version like so:

```
<amazonsqs.init>
    <accessKeyId>MYKEYHERE</accessKeyId>
    <secretAccessKey>SECRETKEYHERE</secretAccessKey>
    <version>2009-02-01</version>
    <region>eu-west-1</region>
    <enableSSL>false</enableSSL>
    <blocking>false</blocking>
</amazonsqs.init>
```

When I run the package on the micro intergrator I keep getting the same error:

> [2020-04-02 10:39:36,257] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer} - Sequence Deployment from the file : /home/ludo/development/wso2_studio_700/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1585816776255TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/seq_msg_to_sqs_1.0.0/seq_msg_to_sqs-1.0.0.xml : Failed. org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}amazonsqs

followed in the same stack trace by:

> Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}amazonsqs

According to the documentation I could find, this was all I needed to do. What am I doing wrong?

FYI:
I get this result when running directly on the micro-integrator from studio, as well as using the docker version I made earlier.

Comment: Also tested this on 6.6.0 standalone. Get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it (after searching well over a day)....

The connector needs to be packaged within your project as well. You can do so by following this guide:
[WSO2 make CAR with connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Connectors+via+Tooling#WorkingwithConnectorsviaTooling-CreatingaCARfileincludingconnectors)

Now to figure out the next of the errors.